# XCode 4.2 and Mac OS 10.7.2 can not identify the iPhone 5.1.1

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, osx-lion

I upgrade my iPhone OS 5 to OS 5.1.1, now my Xcode 4.2 can't identify the device (Mac OS is Lion 10.7.2).

How to overcome this issue? I need any Xcode updation (Xcode 4.2 to Xcode 4.3)?

Comment: You need to use XCode 4.3 + the iOS 5.1 SDK

Comment: ok,has any option for update xcode 4.2 to xcode 4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 4.2 do not have any support for iOS devices with version >= 5.1

Download the latest version of Xcode to dubug on device with iOS 5.1.1

The Xcode is distributed as an app in AppStore. You can download the latest version of Xcode from [here](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12).